# Using variables for asc and desc in order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I understand that I can use variables in the order by section of sql queries like this:

```
order by 
case when @var1 = 'priority' then priority end desc,
case when @var2 = 'report_date' then report_date end asc
```

But how do I use variables for the asc and desc sections too?

Comment: Are you willing to use dynamic SQL?  If not then the only way will be to have 4 cases in your order by, one for the column and one for the order.

Comment: Noting that OP's sort columns don't appear to be *char - better reference for possible duplicates here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147763/dynamic-order-direction and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848340/descending-ascending-parameter-to-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 52, accepted):

without `Dynamic SQL` each option it's clause for example:

```
ORDER BY
  case when @var1 = 'priority asc' THEN priority END ASC ,
  case when @var1 = 'priority desc' then priority end DESC,
  case when @var2 = 'report_date asc' then report_date end ASC,
  case when @var2 = 'report_date desc' then report_date end DESC
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your variable `@var3` stores `'ASC'` or `'DESC'` keywords, you can write something like this:

```
order by 
case when @var1 = 'priority' and @var3 = 'DESC' then priority end DESC,
case when @var1 = 'priority' and @var3 = 'ASC' then priority  end ASC,
case when @var2 = 'report_date' and @var3 = 'ASC' then report_date end ASC,
case when @var2 = 'report_date' and @var3 = 'DESC' then report_date end DESC
```

Comment: what happens if he needs first and second keys? one `ASCENDING` and the other `DESCENDING`? he would need 2 vars, one for each key

Comment: @LuisLL - True. Haven't thought of that :) I was thinking either `priority` or `report_date` will be sorted.  But should get the idea...

Answer (score 8):

You can sort dynamically on many types by introducing a  [multiplier hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147763/dynamic-order-direction/1148056#1148056) to the `Order by`. The implementation will depend on you being able to convert each sortable field to an integer field, like so:

```
DECLARE @Var1 NVARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @Var2 NVARCHAR(3);
DECLARE @OrderHack INT;

SET @Var1 = 'priority';
SET @Var2 = 'DESC';

IF (@Var2 = 'ASC')
    SET @OrderHack = 1;
ELSE
    SET @OrderHack = -1;

SELECT * 
    FROM SortTable
    ORDER BY 
        CASE @var1
            WHEN 'priority'
                THEN CONVERT(INT, [priority]) * @OrderHack
            WHEN 'report_date'
                THEN CONVERT(INT, report_date) * @OrderHack
        END;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c7b0f/2)

**Edit**

Just to clarify, as per `@t-clausen.dk`'s point, the hack is dependent on a a conversion back to a increasing numeric type representing the order. e.g. if you require higher resolution on a `DATETIME` to ensure that the time component is also considered in the sort, the `INT @OrderHack` can be replaced with a `FLOAT` or `DECIMAL` etc. Caveat : Using this technique to sort on `*CHAR` columns could be challenging, especially if case and accent sensitivity is taken into account.

Comment: this will not work when var1 = 'report_date'. If report_date is column type date the conversion will fail. If report_date is a datetime it will be ordered by date, but not by time. It will only work when report_date doesn't contain timepart

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thanks - have clarified. I did qualify the original answer as 'many types' (viz, not all). Fortunately OP's Q seems centered around non string types.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @column VARCHAR(15) = 'object_id'
    , @order CHAR(4) = 'DESC'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = '
SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects 
ORDER BY ' + @column + ' ' + @order

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```