# Variable table name in select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have some tables for storing different file information, like thumbs, images, datasheets, ...

I'm writing a stored procedure to retrieve filename of a specific ID. something like:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE get_file_name(
    @id int,
    @table nvarchar(50)
    )as
    if @table='images'
        select [filename] from images
        where id = @id
    if @table='icons'
        select [filename] from icons
        where id = @id
....
```

How can I rewrite this procedure using `case when` statement or should I just use table name as variable?

Comment: For better design solution I'd recommended to move "file" entity to another table and reference related reference with FOREIGN KEY. Then you won't need any messing with SQL evaluation

Comment: you mean that I have a files table and related all images, icons,... tables to it?

Comment: yes. Then JOINs will help you get any stuff with related file data: `SELECT icons.Name, file.Filename FROM icons INNER JOIN files ON files.Id=icons.FileId WHERE icons.Id=1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use case .. when to switch between a table in the FROM clause (like you can in a [conditional `ORDER BY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207954/using-variables-for-asc-and-desc-in-order-by)). i.e. so the following:

```
select * from 
    case when 1=1
      then t1
      else t2
    end;
```

won't work.

So you'll need to use dynamic SQL. It's best to parameterize the query as far as possible, for example the `@id` value can be parameterized:

```
-- Validate @table is E ['images', 'icons', ... other valid names here]
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'select [filename] from **TABLE** where id = @id';
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '**TABLE**', @table);

sp_executesql @sql, N'@id INT', @id = @id;
```

As with all dynamic Sql, note that `unparameterized` values which are substituted into the query (like `@table`), make the query vulnerable to Sql Injection attacks. As a result, I would suggest that you ensure that `@table` comes from a trusted source, or better still, the value of `@table` is compared to a white list of permissable tables prior to execution of the query.

Comment: well if I should write if clause for each select statement then doesn't my own solution in question look better?

Comment: the reason I was asking this question was that If I add more tables like these I don't want stored procedure need changes, that in this case or mine will need

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani - Good point, I guess you don't want to repeat your query (DRY). I've updated with a tokenization / substitution pattern. I did want to make the point that you would be better off by parameterizing `@id` - it has sql injection safety and query plan cache benefits over simple string catenation. Also, remember to validate @table, as this cannot be parameterized OFC.

Answer (score 3):

Just build SQL string in another variable and EXECUTE it

```
DECLARE @sql AS NCHAR(500)
SET @sql=
    'SELECT [filename] '+
    ' FROM '+@table+
    ' WHERE id = @id'
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_file_name(
    @id int,
    @table nvarchar(50)
    )as

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
SET @SQL = 'select [filename] from ' + @table + ' where id = ' + @id
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```