# order by datetime dynamically

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

i modified the code like below:

```
declare @filterBy as nvarchar(255)  = 'C1'
declare @order as nvarchar(255)  = 'asc'
declare @globOrder as nvarchar(255) = 'CONVERT(DateTime, C3,101) ASC'


SELECT TOP (7000)

        [Project1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], 
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [Project1].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], 
        [Project1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], 
        [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], 
        [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], 
        [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], 
        [Project1].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], 
        [Project1].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], 
        [Project1].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], 
        [Project1].[Libelle1] AS [Libelle1]
        FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], [Project1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], [Project1].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], [Project1].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], [Project1].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], [Project1].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], [Project1].[Libelle1] AS [Libelle1], [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], [Project1].[C3] AS [C3], [Project1].[C4] AS [C4], [Project1].[C5] AS [C5], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CASE when @filterBy = 'DateNaissance' and @order = 'asc'  THEN CONVERT(DateTime, [Project1].C3,101) END asc , CASE when @filterBy = 'DateNaissance' and @order = 'desc'  THEN CONVERT(DateTime, [Project1].C3,101) END desc,CASE when @filterBy <> 'DateNaissance' and @order = 'asc'  THEN @filterBy END ASC , CASE when @filterBy <> 'DateNaissance' and @order = 'desc'  THEN @filterBy END desc) AS [row_number] , [Project1].profil AS prof
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] AS [IDC_IDCONTACT], 
                [Extent1].[IDC_NOSOC] AS [IDC_NOSOC], 
                [Extent2].[ICP_PRENOM] AS [ICP_PRENOM], 
                [Extent4].[ADC_CDPOSTAL] AS [ADC_CDPOSTAL], 
                [Extent4].[ADC_VILLE] AS [ADC_VILLE], 
                [Extent5].[Libelle] AS [Libelle], 
                [Extent6].[Libelle] AS [Libelle1], 
                [Extent1].[IDC_NOM] AS [C1], 
                [Extent2].[ICP_NMNAISS] AS [C2], 
                [Extent1].[IDC_CDPROFIL_CONTACT]  AS profil,
                 CAST( [Extent2].[ICP_DTNAISS] AS datetime2) AS [C3], 
                 CAST( [Extent3].[ICR_DTCREA_ENTREPRISE] AS datetime2) AS [C4], 
                CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE  CAST( [Extent1].[IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE] AS nvarchar(max)) END AS [C5]
                FROM      [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT] AS [Extent1]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT_PHYSIQUE] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent2].[ICP_IDCONTACT] 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[IDENTITE_CONTACT_PROFESSIONNEL] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent3].[ICR_IDCONTACT]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[ADRESSE_CONTACT] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent1].[IDC_IDCONTACT] = [Extent4].[ADC_IDADR]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[Ref_Profil_Contact] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[IDC_CDPROFIL_CONTACT] = [Extent5].[Cod]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [mdw].[Ref_Statut] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[IDC_CDSTATUTSOC] = [Extent6].[Cod]  WHERE IDC_CDPORTEFEUILLE IN (0108,0208,1808))  AS [Project1]
        )  AS [Project1]WHERE [Project1].[row_number]  > 0
```

it work when @filterBy have the value 'DateNaissance' but it's not working when it takes another value , the probleme is i can't pass a variable to order by

Comment: Which is your DBMS? (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql)

Comment: i'm trying to execute it from SSMS

Comment: Please put break points in your query and try to debug the procedure.

Comment: Look at this [link](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-order-by)

Comment: Add @order inside case statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709775/can-i-store-sql-server-sort-order-in-a-variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709775/can-i-store-sql-server-sort-order-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with two CASEs:

```
ORDER BY
        CASE UPPER(@order)
        WHEN 'ASC'
        THEN CONVERT(DateTime, C3,101)
        END ASC,
        CASE UPPER(@order)
        WHEN 'DESC'
        THEN CONVERT(DateTime, C3,101)
        END DESC
```

It was answered here already:
[DESCENDING/ASCENDING Parameter to a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848340/descending-ascending-parameter-to-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use declare var in your order by. You can use **CASE** statement if you want, something like this:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE  
        WHEN @order = 'asc'
        THEN CONVERT(DateTime, C3,101) ASC
        WHEN @order = 'desc'
        THEN CONVERT(DateTime, C3,101)  DESC
    END
```

Comment: He can use *alias*, you probably mean he can not use variable as he use it.

Comment: Aliases can be used, but not a variable for ASC or DESC.

Comment: I comment the text "...You can't use alias in your order by..." - this is not true @Vojtěch Dohnal.

Comment: how i can use alias ?

Comment: like you can see in the edited version of my question , i tried this solution , it work for datetim because i mention the name of colone(C3) but not for the other , because i pass a variable (filterBy)

Answer (score 0):

Just change you row_number logic line with below code:

declare @order as nvarchar(255)  = 'desc'
        declare @filterBy as nvarchar(255)  = 'C3'

```
    select row_number() OVER (ORDER BY CASE @filterBy WHEN 'DateNaissance' THEN CONVERT(DateTime, col1,101) + @order END  , @filterBy DESC) AS [row_number] ,col1
    from
    (select cast(GETDATE()AS datetime2) AS col1
    union all
    select cast(GETDATE()- 2 AS datetime2) AS col1) base
```

You are using @order by after end of case which is through error the correct way to use order by in the case before End

Comment: this is not working , i get the same error : can't convert datetime to string

Comment: i try with create logic which worked i will edit the post and send you the logic if you change the logic as your it will give same error.